# SQL server remote access

Tags: sql-server, windows, firewall, msdtc

I am trying to connect to a remote SQL database.

I have the access and the sql server is configured for remote login.
I can login to the server from another machine (B) but not from my machine (A).

Both the machines (A and B) are on same domain. None have their IP white-listed.

In short, I do not think there is an issue on sql server side.

On my side,
I tried modifying DTC and firewall properties. (Not sure if the modifications are correct).

Could anybody please help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to connect through software? You said "SQL Server" so I'll assume you're talking about using SSMS to connect to a server?

You said that you can login to the SQL server from the box that the server is on but not from a remote computer. This sounds like a permissions problem to me.

Is the account you created setup for Windows authentication? Should you be using a local SQL server account instead?

Some more information could help everyone troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

you set blind address in the sql server config?